# Go Glide Error "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: go

I am trying to manage my Go project with glide.

I executed `glide update`, but got `The system cannot find the path specified` error as below.

```
C:\path\to\myproject\src>glide update
[INFO]  Downloading dependencies. Please wait...
[INFO]  --> Fetching google.golang.org/appengine.
[INFO]  --> Fetching cloud.google.com/go.
[INFO]  --> Fetching golang.org/x/net.
[INFO]  --> Fetching github.com/gin-gonic/gin.
[INFO]  --> Fetching google.golang.org/api.
[INFO]  --> Fetching golang.org/x/oauth2.
[INFO]  --> Detected semantic version. Setting version for github.com/gin-gonic/gin to v1.1.4.
[INFO]  --> Detected semantic version. Setting version for google.golang.org/appengine to v1.0.0.
[INFO]  --> Detected semantic version. Setting version for cloud.google.com/go to v0.7.0.
[INFO]  Resolving imports
[INFO]  Found Godeps.json file in C:\Users\myhome\.glide\cache\src\https-github.com-gin-gonic-gin
[INFO]  --> Parsing Godeps metadata...
[INFO]  --> Fetching github.com/manucorporat/sse.
[INFO]  --> Setting version for github.com/manucorporat/sse to ee05b128a739a0fb76c7ebd3ae4810c1de808d6d.
[INFO]  --> Fetching github.com/mattn/go-isatty.
[INFO]  --> Setting version for golang.org/x/net to f315505cf3349909cdf013ea56690da34e96a451.
[INFO]  --> Fetching github.com/golang/protobuf.
[INFO]  --> Setting version for github.com/golang/protobuf to 2402d76f3d41f928c7902a765dfc872356dd3aad.
[INFO]  --> Fetching github.com/googleapis/gax-go.
[INFO]  --> Fetching gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8.
[INFO]  --> Setting version for gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8 to c193cecd124b5cc722d7ee5538e945bdb3348435.
[INFO]  --> Fetching gopkg.in/yaml.v2.
[INFO]  --> Fetching golang.org/x/sys.
[INFO]  --> Fetching google.golang.org/grpc.
[INFO]  --> Fetching google.golang.org/genproto.
[ERROR] Error scanning github.com\golang\protobuf\ptypes\any: open C:\Users\myhome\.glide\cache\src\https-github.com-golang-protobuf\ptypes\any: The system cannot find the path specified.
[ERROR] Failed to retrieve a list of dependencies: Error resolving imports
```

Actually there is not `C:\Users\myhome\.glide\cache\src\https-github.com-golang-protobuf\ptypes` directory, but I can not understand why this directory is missed.

[image]

My `glide.yaml` is as follows.

```
package: .
import:
- package: cloud.google.com/go
  version: ^0.7.0
  subpackages:
  - bigquery
  - civil
- package: github.com/gin-gonic/gin
  version: ^1.1.4
- package: golang.org/x/net
  subpackages:
  - context
- package: golang.org/x/oauth2
  subpackages:
  - google
- package: google.golang.org/api
  subpackages:
  - iterator
- package: google.golang.org/appengine
  version: ^1.0.0
  subpackages:
  - datastore
  - log
  - memcache
  - remote_api
```

How can I fix?

Comment: What's the `GOPATH` value?

Comment: @zerkms `GOPATH` is C:\path\to\myproject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the `github.com/golang/protobuf` version `2402d76f3d41f928c7902a765dfc872356dd3aad` which `github.com/gin-gonic/gin` wants does not has `ptype`. I added below lines to `glide.yaml`.

```
- package: github.com/golang/protobuf
  version: b50ceb1fa9818fa4d78b016c2d4ae025593a7ce3
```

`b50ceb1fa9818fa4d78b016c2d4ae025593a7ce3` is the current newest commit.

The error has gone. But I am not sure this is the straightforward way because I still have the warning below.

```
[WARN]  Conflict: github.com/golang/protobuf rev is currently b50ceb1fa9818fa4d78b016c2d4ae025593a7ce3, but github.com/gin-gonic/gin wants 2402d76f3d41f928c7902a765dfc872356dd3aad
```

If another way is desirable, please advise me.